# Is there an easier way to take multiple actions types in redux-saga?

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-saga

I have redux saga that is supposed to fetch product from DB to redux state. But it has some dependencies, which has to be fetched first.

```
const result = yield take(['GET_CATEGORIES_SUCCESS', 'GET_TYPES_SUCCESS'])
```

Request for these dependencies is fired separately when the page loads. Problem is that they return in random order and I need to `take` both of them if I want to proceed with the rest of the function.

I managed to do just that with this crazy contraption, which works, but is there an easier way to do this?

Another problem is that if both of these

```
const result = yield take(['GET_CATEGORIES_SUCCESS', 'GET_TYPES_SUCCESS'])
```

are returned before `getProductSaga()` can even fire, then whole function gets stuck.

This is full code for this saga:

```
export function* getProductSaga(action) {
    try {
        const result = yield take(['GET_CATEGORIES_SUCCESS', 'GET_TYPES_SUCCESS'])
        if (result.type === 'GET_CATEGORIES_SUCCESS') {
            yield take(['GET_TYPES_SUCCESS'])
        } else {
            yield take(['GET_CATEGORIES_SUCCESS'])
        }
        const product = yield call(api.product.get, action.id)
        yield put(getProductSuccess(product))
        yield put(setEditLoadingSuccess(action.id))
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.response.data.errors)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I managed to do just that with this crazy contraption, which works, but is there easier way to do this?

Yep, use `all`. It will run an arbitrary number of effects, and wait until they all complete before moving on to the next line.

```
export function* getProductSaga(action) {
  try {
    // You can leave off the left hand side if you don't care about the results
    const [categoriesSuccessAction, typesSuccessAction] = yield all([
      take('GET_CATEGORIES_SUCCESS'),
      take('GET_TYPES_SUCCESS'),
    ]);

    const product = yield call(api.product.get, action.id)
    // etc
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.response.data.errors)
  }
}
```

> Another problem is that if both of these [...] are returned before getProductSaga() can even fire, then whole function gets stuck.

That's true. You'll only want to listen for these actions if you have a reasonable expectation that they will occur. Unfortunately, since i don't know how the rest of your app is architected, i can't make a very specific recommendation. Perhaps you could check if the store contains some value, and if so skip the `take`s.